# How the potential difference (PD) between two electrodes changes with electrolyte concentration and distance?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, electronics, home-experiment, electrochemistry

I set up the following experiment

[image: The set up of the experiment.]

I keep the black probe fixed to the left electrode. I moved the red probe at different points. I measure a voltage, basically the potential difference (PD) between the left electrode at the point.

**Question**: At the $4$cm line, from $0$cm to $15$cm there is a large variation of PD which I hypothesized should have been almost the same. However, on the 24 cm lines, there is minimal variation in the PD. I started with a 0.5 M solution of NaCl. I don't get why at the 4cm line there is a huge variation but at the 24cm line there is very little variation (I connected the electrodes to a 10V battery).

Here is a [link to my Excel file with the data I collected](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10UdE7DtFMUs8bzQQkaYkxNEjvbolxMHB/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=107951820316201103061&rtpof=true&sd=true).

> E.g., going down as in the picture from $0$cm (top) to $15$cm (bottom):
>
> $4$cm vertical line: $1.72$,   $2.75$, $3.3$, $3.54$
>
> $24$cm vertical line: $8.15$,   $8.03$, $8$, $7.86$

Comment: Given the concentration of the saltwater and the applied 10V, you should be electrolyzing the saltwater and should observe gas bubbles on both electrodes. Do you observe gas bubbles and, if so, are they forming relatively uniformly distributed on the electrode surfaces?

Comment: It seems that you have larger PD variations along the horizontal top line (compare it with the PD along the horizontal bottom line). Maybe this  is due to where you put the connectors, that are probably touching the liquid. Try putting one connector on the bottom, or both at the centre. Also, you may edit the question (that is potentially interesting IMO) so it could be voted for reopening.

Comment: When data isn't what you expect, it often helps to expand the data space.  What potential do you measure along a 1 cm line? What happens if you connect one or both leads to the other end of the electrodes? What happens if you swap the the positive and negative leads? What are the electrodes made of? Are they identical? The title to the question refers to "electrolyte concentration", but this isn't mentioned in the actual question. Have you tried with different concentrations?